# Insert timestamp into SQL Server 2000 using .asp - yes this is old stuff

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am trying to insert a time stamp into SQL Server 2000 using classic ASP. The rest of the string works except for the timestamp. I am getting a blank insert with this query.

```
sActionSQL = "Insert Into [mydatabase].dbo.AppUsers" 
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " ([UserID], [AuthorityLevel], [Stores], [Area],     
[Password], [DateAdded])"
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " Values ('" & UCase(Request.Form("UserID")) & "'"
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " , " & Request.Form("AuthorityLevel") 
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " , '" & Request.Form("Stores") & "'"
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " , '" & Request.Form("cboAreaDirector") & "'"
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " , '" & sUserPassword  & "'"
sActionSQL = sActionSQL & " , '" & (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) & "')
```

The `DateAdded` column is a `varchar(50)`. Should I be using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `DATEADD`?

Comment: Can you use `now`?  Or if you just want the time, I believe `time` is built in as well.

Comment: Thanks sgeddes, now worked!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, neither. I don't know of any built-in object like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and `DateAdd` is for what it says on the tin: for adding dates. Why aren't you using `Now` or `Date`? (`Now` is the current system date and time, and `Date` is the current date, no time portion.)

Comment: Thanks Martha, I used the now as stated earlier, it works fine.